# Solr dataimport - pass variable to query

Tags: solr

I am trying to pass a variable to my solr (4.10.0) server when calling the dataimport full import command.

I have searched around the net and found several examples but none of them seem to be working for me.

The URL that i call looks likes this:

"http://xx.xx.xx.xx:XXXX/solr/mycore/dataimport?command=full-import**&MAXid=1234**&clean=false"

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE LASTMOD  >= '2014-04-30' AND 
('${dataimporter.request.clean}' != 'false' OR MYID > '${dataimporter.request.MAXid}')
```

When I call the URL the import starts but it imports everything.

Do I need to use DIH.request.MAXid instead of dataimporter?

Comment: The syntax is correct. Probably there is some problem around the meaning of MAXid. Whats the meaning of that? In your query you're getting all rows that MYID is greater than MAXid. Is it correct? It wouldn't be `MYID < '${dataimporter.request.MAXid}'`?

Comment: MaxID is the ID of the last record in Solr (i query Solr before to get it). I dont have a last mod column in the db but the ids are in order - so i want to grab all records from the db where their Ids are greater than the maxid. Thanks